# How to force IE-8 32 bit for Win7 and not break IE-7 on WinXP?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-7, windows-xp, operating-system

We're running an C#.net app with users who might have WinXP or might have Win7.  The WinXP are mostly on IE-7, the Win7 users have IE-8.  Within the application, a web page needs to be displayed, and it will only work on a 32 bit browser (Crystal Reports).

In WinXP, the browser is called with C:\Program Files\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe.

In Win7, the 64 bit browser is called with the same, but the 32 bit browser is called with C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe.

So, we need to determine the OS of the user, and then use the appropriate IE.  Or, we need to somehow make IE 32 bit the default browser.

When we first encountered this, I was one of the few Win7 users, and we remapped the iexplore in my pc to point to the 32 bit IE.  That worked for months, until we got an upgrade, and it broke IE so bad that it wouldn't start at all, and I ended up getting my pc reimaged.  I don't think that's a good solution for our general users!

Should we somehow get the OS of the user, and then call the appropriate IE?  How would that be done?  Or, is there a better way to handle this?  There will be a mixture of OSs for probably quite a while, perhaps a few years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just call `Process.Start(@"\path\to\file.html")` to open the page in the user's default browser.

If you really need the path to 32-bit IE, call

```
Path.Combine(
    Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ProgramFilesX86),  
    @"Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe"
)
```

Comment: @McKay: I was assuming a local file.

Comment: He's stated that only 32bit IE can handle the webpage - it sounds like is uses a 32bit ActiveX control.

Comment: Yes, but a local file might be programmed to open in an editor, but a url will launch the default browser.

Comment: @David: I don't think the default browser will be IE x64.

Comment: @McKay: HTML files are rarely if ever defaulted to open with an editor.

Comment: @SLaks Correct, but it could happen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the default browser is the 32 bit one.

Answer (score 0):

```
Process.Start("http://www.example.com/path/to/file.html");
```

Starting a URL will open the default browser. This might not be IE though. I'd also recommend formatting the url with the protocol and everything else.